# Programatically disable series on nvd3 Horizontal Multi-Bar Chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

The issue is that I have a lot of series on my chart and, on load, I would like only 3 selected.

Is there a way to 'disable' ( hide ) a series on [nvd3 Horizontal Multi-Bar Chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html)? ( I'm looking for the click series behavior but programatically )

I have tried to send JSON with `'visible': false,` but it not works.

```
var data=[{"key": "Series 1",
           "visible": false, 
           "values": [{"value": 10000.0, "label": ...
```

Following [@shabeer90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283118/shabeer90) instructions tested with:

```
           "disabled": true,
```

In this case series is disabled but don't allow to switch to enable clicking series circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do this directly with NVD3 (at least not without modifying the source). However, you can trigger this programatically by simulating the click on the legend element:

```
d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series")
        .each(function(d) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
        });
```

Assuming that your data has an attribute `visible` that determines whether the series should be shown or not, you can filter based on that:

```
d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.visible == false; })
        .each(function(d) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
        });
```

If you're using a transition to create the graph, remember to call this code when the transition has finished. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzrgdzed/2/).

Comment: Nice answer! You know if there is a way to complete it with out transitions? ( http://jsfiddle.net/au33ev7a/ )

Comment: This is a bit trickier (again not directly supported). What you could is use the latest version of NVD3 which allows to set a transition duration, set that to 0 before clicking and reset to the default afterwards. Then you should also call `unselect` immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/au33ev7a/1/

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, enought for me. Thanks for share your knowledge.