# manipulating legend by selectInput - multibarChart in rCharts

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rcharts

I created a simple app which includes a `selectInput` widget and a bar plot in `rCharts`. What I want to accomplish is to create the plot with a legend with all three books but by default show only a book which is chosen by the widget. So when I change from `Book1` to `Book2` the plot will show initially only info about `Book2` but legend plot will include `Book1` and `Book3` (both disabled by default) - if I want to I could choose `Book1` or `Book3` anytime. I believe it is JS problem so I tried to solve it but nothing changed. Any ideas how to handle it? Thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

books <- c('Book1','Book2','Book3')
df <- data.frame(book = rep(books, each = 10), 
                 year = rep(2000:2009,3),
                 sale = sample(100:1000, 30, replace = T))

ui <- shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
            HTML("
            <script>
                 $( document ).ready(function() {
                        if ( $(\"select#book div.selectize-dropdown div[data-value='Book1']\").hasClass('selected')) {
                              console.log('true');
                              $('#nvd3Plot .nv-legend g.nv-series').eq(1).addClass('disabled');
                              $('#nvd3Plot .nv-legend g.nv-series').eq(2).addClass('disabled');
                        }
                        else {
                              console.log('false');

                        }
                 }); 
            </script>"),

            selectInput('book', 'Select a book', choices = books, selected = 'Book1'),
            showOutput("nvd3Plot", "nvd3")
      )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$nvd3Plot <- renderChart2({

            chartObject <- nPlot(sale ~ year, group = "book", data = df, type = "multiBarChart")
            chartObject$chart(
                  showControls = FALSE
                  )

            return(chartObject)
      })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update**

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938221/programatically-disable-series-on-nvd3-horizontal-multi-bar-chart) but actually I don't have any idea how to implement it in R.

Comment: i didn't found yet how it could be done but if you look here [nvd3](i didn't found yet) you could see _Multibar Chart with Controls_ in the example they use controle to filter the data set on the sex (male, female). May be their is something to do in this way.

Comment: Could you send me this link, please?

Comment: My mistake wrong paste. http://ramnathv.github.io/posts/rcharts-nvd3/

Comment: What I see in this example is double filtering based on two variables. My problem is quite different.

Comment: I know but they used UI side event with java script to switch value depending on the filtering. If you can have a look how it's done may be that could help you

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938221/programatically-disable-series-on-nvd3-horizontal-multi-bar-chart. According to the author, it is not possible in nvd3 directly.

Comment: But he provide a solution. The main question is how to implement it in renderObject in shiny.

Comment: may be in the `chartObject$templates$script` by creating the chartObject and then adding a character variable containing the `js` into the `chartObject ` server side before render it

Comment: take a look to `chartObject$print()` this is the output used by shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938221/programatically-disable-series-on-nvd3-horizontal-multi-bar-chart), you could use a custom message handler to programatically click on the legend.

You could add, in your `ui.R`:

```
tags$script('
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("change_selected_book",
        function(book) {
          d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series.disabled")
          .each(function(d) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
         });

          d3.select("g.nv-legendWrap").selectAll("g.nv-series").filter(
            function(d) { return d.key != book; })
        .each(function(d) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
        });
        });
    ')
```

and in your `server.R`:

```
 observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "change_selected_book", input$book)
  })
```

The code clicks on all of the disabled series, and once all series are enabled, it clicks on the legend of all the books except the one the user has selected to disable them.

One drawback is that the `selectInput` element is created before the graph so it initially displays all three books until the user selects one.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Regarding selectInput drawback, do you know any option to avoid it?